# How to verify if words are in array and get array position value?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the `category_id` of a product by checking whether the `category_name` is found in the `product_name`.

Take this array

```
$women_apparel = array('Tank Top', 'T-Shirt');
```

Now those 2 product_names :

```
$product_name1 = 'Next Level 6733 Ladies Triblend Racerback Tank Top';
$product_name2 = 'Los Angeles Apparel 2332 Fine Jersey Short Sleeve Cropped T-Shirt';
```

I'm trying this :

```
if (in_array($product_name1, $women_apparel)) {
 echo 'this product belongs to category X';
}
```

Desired Output :

```
Product 1 belongs to category 0
Product 2 belongs to category 1
```

How can I accomplish this dynamically (no hard-code)?

Comment: Maybe `implode` the `women_apparel` with `|`, `preg_quote` the terms, and then add word boundaries. I think with these three you could use `preg_match`.

Comment: Are these in a database?

Comment: @user3783243: No. Hard-coded arrays like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar_text to count similar string in a category like this.

```
<?php 



  $women_apparel = array('Tank Top', 'T-Shirt');


$product_name1 = 'Next Level 6733 Ladies Triblend Racerback Tank Top';
$product_name2 = 'Los Angeles Apparel 2332 Fine Jersey Short Sleeve Cropped T-Shirt';

    foreach ($women_apparel as $key=>$value) {
        if (similar_text($product_name1, $value) >= strlen($value)) {
            echo "Product 1 belongs to category $key ";
        }
        else if (similar_text($product_name2, $value) >= strlen($value)) {
            echo "Product 2 belongs to category $key ";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter . match the values of an array using a callback function:

```
   <?php


$women_apparel = array('Tank Top', 'T-Shirt', 'jeans');
//Add the product value in array.
$product ['product 1'] = 'Next Level 6733 Ladies Triblend Racerback Tank Top';
$product ['product 2'] = 'Los Angeles Apparel 2332 Fine Jersey Short Sleeve Cropped T-Shirt';
$product ['product 3'] = 'product of jeans';

    for($i=0; $i<count($women_apparel);$i++){
        $value = $women_apparel[$i];

        $match = array_filter($product, function($var) use ($value) { return preg_match("/\b$value\b/i", $var); });

        //If the women_apparel value in product gets the key of product ($match)[0]) and display the required output.
        echo array_keys($match)[0].' belongs to category '.$i.'<br/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, try the above solution it will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I thought in a dynamic approach creating the function `searchProductCategory` that receives two arrays, the first should contain the products name and the second the categories.

```
<?php
$categories = ['Tank Top', 'T-Shirt'];

$products = [
    'Next Level 6733 Ladies Triblend Racerback Tank Top',
    'Los Angeles Apparel 2332 Fine Jersey Short Sleeve Cropped T-Shirt'
];

searchProductCategory($products, $categories);

function searchProductCategory(array $products, array $categories) : void
{
    foreach ($products as $product_index => $product) {
        $product_index++;

        foreach ($categories as $category_index => $category) {
            if (similar_text($product, $category) >= strlen($category)) {
                echo "Product {$product_index} belongs to category $category_index <br />";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it by using a custom function with `array_walk`

```
$women_apparel = array('Tank Top', 'T-Shirt');
$product_name1 = 'Next Level 6733 Ladies Triblend Racerback Tank Top';
$product_name2 = 'Los Angeles Apparel 2332 Fine Jersey Short Sleeve Cropped T-Shirt';
searchForCategory($product_name1, $women_apparel);//call for product 1
searchForCategory($product_name2, $women_apparel);// call for product 2

function searchForCategory($pname, $catArr){
    $res = [];
    array_walk($catArr, function($v, $k) use($pname, &$res){
        if(strpos($pname, $v) !== false )
            echo $pname.' : belongs to category '.$k.'<br/>';
    });
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/eQr2f)

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for pointing that out, it has been fixed now